# Fitting data for an implicit function with two parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, data, implicit

I have an implicit function of independent variable `sB` and dependent variable `H` with two parameters `kV` and `km`, describing an experiment.

```
kH*(HB - H) + kW*cBWA*(1/(1 + kaW/HB) - 1/(1 + kaW/H)) + 
(kV*1/2*(sB - kV - km + Sqrt[(sB - kV - km)^2 + 4*km*sB]))/(km + 1/2*(sB - kV - km + Sqrt[(sB - kV - km)^2 + 4*km*sB]))*
(nA/(1 + H/kaA) - nB/(1 + kaB/H)) == 0
```

I experimentally obtained the points and values of the `sB` and `H`.

```
dotsA = {{0.5076923076923077, 7.751879699248121},
{1.0153846153846153,7.604511278195489},
{1.7769230769230773,7.4},
{2.576923076923077, 7.209022556390978},
{3.2692307692307696,7.070676691729323},
{4.530769230769231, 7.003007518796992}};

dotsconcA = 10^-dotsA
{{0.310676, 1.7706*10^-8}, {0.0965196, 2.48593*10^-8}, {0.0167139, 
  3.98107*10^-8}, {0.00264897, 6.17984*10^-8}, {0.000537984, 
  8.49813*10^-8}, {0.0000294599, 9.93099*10^-8}}
```

From the article, I know that the values of the parameters `kV=0.41*10^-3 km=13.1*10^-3` are obtained using the least squares method, but the article does not describe this in sufficient detail and I do not understand how to implement this in Wolfram Mathematica.

I obtained a function graph using the found parameters and `FindRoot` function

```
f1[H_, sB_] := kH*(HB - H) + kW*cBWA*(1/(1 + kaW/HB) - 1/(1 + kaW/H)) + 
(kV*1/2*(sB - kV - km + Sqrt[(sB - kV - km)^2 + 4*km*sB]))/(km + 1/2*(sB - kV - km + Sqrt[(sB - kV - km)^2 + 4*km*sB]))*
(nA/(1 + H/kaA) - nB/(1 + kaB/H));

lst1 = Table[{-Log[10, sB], -Log[10, H /. FindRoot[f1[H, sB] == 0, {H, 10^-9}]]}, {sB, 10^-5, 1, 0.0001}]
```

and I compared it to experimentally obtained points.

[image]

This plot looks the same as in the article
How can I find the `kV` and `km` parameters by myself?

**Update**: Forgot about the constants

```
kaA = 4.3*10^-7; kaB = 5.6*10^-10; kaW = 6.2*10^-8; nA = 1; nB = 2;
kH = 1; kW = 1; HB = 10^-7; cBWA = 1*10^-3;
kV111 = 0.41*10^-3; km111 = 13.1*10^-3;
```

Comment: What are all the constants: H, HB, kH, kW, sB, .. ?

Comment: Your equation/function involve the variables/parameters, `{cBWA, H, HB, kaA, kaB, kaW, kH, km, kV, kW, nA, nB, sB}`. You presumably have assigned some values to some of the parameters. What values are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about constants
`kaA = 4.3*10^-7; kaB = 5.6*10^-10; kaW = 6.2*10^-8;
nA = 1; nB = 2; kH = 1; kW = 1; HB = 10^-7; cBWA = 1*10^-3;
kV111 = 0.41*10^-3;
km111 = 13.1*10^-3;`

Comment: Can you supply the reference to the article?

Comment: It's a series of five articles and they are not in public domain. They titled "Kinetic Model of pH-based Potentiometric Enzymic Sensors" by S. Glab. Part 1 about theory and derivation of inaccurate model. We did the same calculations and corrected them to our model above. Part 2 explains data fitting for model with an example experiment. We needed part 3 because the experiment in it corresponded to ours and I took all the constants, data and first plot for comparison from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we found our fit and now I will describe how if someone will face the same problem. First of all, we simplified our model to a polynomial of the 4th degree.

```
f1[sB_,H_,kV_,km_]:=(H+kaA) (H+kaB) (H+kaW) (HB+kaW) ((-H+HB) kH+(cBWA (-H+HB) kaW kW)/((H+kaW) (HB+kaW))+(kV (-kaA (H+kaB) nA+H (H+kaA) nB) (km+kV-sB-Sqrt[(km+kV-sB)^2+4 km sB]))/((H+kaA) (H+kaB) (km-kV+sB+Sqrt[(km+kV-sB)^2+4 km sB])))
```

Secondly, we used Solve to find a solution for **H** and defined a function of **sB** and 2 parameters **km** and **kV**.

```
poly4[sB_,kV_,km_]:=H/.Solve[f1[sB,H,kV,km]==0&&0<=sB<=1,H,PositiveReals,InverseFunctions->True][[1]]
```

Thus, we turned the implicit function to explicit one. And finally the fitting

```
FindFit[dotsconcA,poly4[sB,kV,km], {{km,0.00001}, {kV,0.00001}}, sB]
km->0.006484, kV->0.0003568
```

Unfortunately, these parameters do not match those in the article, but when comparing the plots it looks great. Also, the fitting process takes about an hour, but that's a problem for the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know how to accept your own answer until now...

Here a simple approach to solve the implicit problem using "NMinimize"

```
mini = NMinimize[
Total@Map[f1[#[[2]], #[[1]]] Conjugate[f1[#[[2]], #[[1]]]] &,dotsconcA ]
, {km, kV} ]

Show[{ListPlot[dotsconcA], 
ContourPlot[(f1[H, sB] /. mini[[2]]) == 0, {sB, 0.0001, .35}, {H,10^-8, 10^-7}]}]
```

[image]