# Solve constraints don't work properly

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, fitting

So in my previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296517/fitting-data-for-an-implicit-function-with-two-parameters), I was trying to find two parameters kV and km for an implicit function using FindFit(FF) command and I did it but the problem is that it takes around an **hour** to do it. Using EvaluationMonitor on FF, I found that the problem lies in Solve and that FF solves it with "empty" variables and only after that it starts to fit parameters.

```
kaA = 4.3*10^-7; kaB = 5.6*10^-10; kaW = 6.2*10^-8; nA = 1; nB = 2;
kH = 1; kW = 1; HB = 10^-7; cBWA = 1*10^-3; kV1 = 0.41*10^-3; km1 = 13.1*10^-3;

f1[sB_,H_,kV_,km_]:=(H+kaA) (H+kaB) (H+kaW) (HB+kaW) ((-H+HB) kH+(cBWA (-H+HB) kaW kW)/((H+kaW) (HB+kaW))+(kV (-kaA (H+kaB) nA+H (H+kaA) nB) (km+kV-sB-Sqrt[(km+kV-sB)^2+4 km sB]))/((H+kaA) (H+kaB) (km-kV+sB+Sqrt[(km+kV-sB)^2+4 km sB])))
```

The **f** polynomial as well as original model is equal to 0. Using Solve I found solution for H and turned the function to explicit one. I Solved it without the colon :, and it took the same amount of time as FF. After that using FF was WAY faster, because we don't solve it every time, but there was another problem. Some constraints that I wrote are not working in Solve.

```
poly1[sB_,kV_,km_]:=H/.Solve[f1[sB,H,kV,km]==0&&0<=sB<=1&&kV>0&&km>0,H,PositiveReals,InverseFunctions->True][[1]]
```

[image]
Don't pay attention to the Root, it's okay. The problem is that the constraint non-strict constraints 0<=sB<=1 turns to strict ones 0<sB<1. This is unacceptable because my data for sB contains 0 and 1. Why is this happening?

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in 14.0 on Windows 10. The  command `H/.Solve[...]` is running without any response for a long time.

Comment: It really does take a long time, but it works trust me. I doubt that OS have anything to do with that. I added constants from previous question. Did you tried compute it without them?

Comment: My comp is not strong though 14.0 under Windows 10 runs on my comp.

Comment: You override the constraint by specifying the domain as `PositiveReals`. To be consistent, the domain should be `NonnegativeReals`. Or just use either `Reals` or no domain specification.

Comment: It `NonnegativeReals` gives similar result `Root[] if km>0 && sB>0 && kV>0` and won't let me use 0 for sB.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I tried writing constraints like this,

```
poly1[sB_, kV_, km_] = ha/. Solve[f1[sB,ha,kV,km]==0, ha, NonNegativeReals, InverseFunctions -> True,Assumptions -> kV > 0 && km > 0 && sB >= 0][[1]]
```

and now everything works as it should and I can set 0 for sB
[image]